# How to automatically blacklist attackers

Tags: node.js, express, web-crawler, blacklist

The log files of our nodejs server contain a lot of entries like:

```
Jul 16 21:43:30 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /MyAdmin/index.php
Jul 16 21:43:31 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /phpMyAdmin1/index.php
Jul 16 21:43:31 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /phpMyAdmin123/index.php
Jul 16 21:43:31 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /pwd/index.php
Jul 16 21:43:31 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /phpMyAdmina/index.php
Jul 16 21:43:32 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /phpMydmin/index.php
Jul 16 21:43:32 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /phpMyAdmins/index.php
Jul 16 21:43:32 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /phpMyAdmin._/index.php
Jul 16 21:43:33 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /phpMyAdmin._2/index.php
Jul 16 21:43:33 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /phpmyadmin2222/index.php
Jul 16 21:43:33 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /phpmyadmin3333/index.php
Jul 16 21:43:33 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /php2MyAdmin/index.php
Jul 16 21:43:34 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /phpiMyAdmin/index.php
Jul 16 21:43:34 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /phpNyAdmin/index.php
Jul 16 21:43:34 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /1/index.php
Jul 16 21:43:34 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /download/index.php
Jul 16 21:43:34 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /phpMyAdmin_111/index.php
Jul 16 21:43:35 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /phpmadmin/index.php
Jul 16 21:43:35 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /321/index.php
Jul 16 21:43:35 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /123131/index.php
Jul 16 21:43:35 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /phpMyAdminn/index.php
Jul 16 21:43:36 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /phpMyAdminhf/index.php
Jul 16 21:43:36 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /sbb/index.php
Jul 16 21:43:37 ip-172-31-74-106 node[18223]: redirecting visitor of 184.72.177.213 for page /WWW/phpMyAdmin/index.php
```

This is obviously some kind of bot that searches for an exploit to take down our server.

Is there a way to automatically detect these kind of abusers and add them to a blacklist ?

Perhaps an express plugin.

Comment: Try a rate-limiter, and add the action you want when the limit is reached. In this case, you would add them to a black-list. I use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit.

Comment: I would think that you would want to block these before they get to your Node app. If you aren't running any PHP apps on the same server then why not redirect and blackhole these reqs at the server level? Assuming you're proxying outside traffic through nginx to your app for example, set up a rule in nginx and deal with it there.

Comment: Actually it is just a simple nodejs project which launches express, (no nginx). Is that asking for trouble ? (ps: not running any php) - the whole thing runs on an amazon aws ec2 micro instance.

Comment: just reading about "amazon cloudfront" perhaps that's the solution.

Comment: actually "AWS WAF" and "AWS Shield" may be what I need.

Comment: @bvdb you should always proxy a Node app through nginx or Apache or similar - proxy in nginx is dead simple. Another good option is [Traefik](https://traefik.io/). Yes, there are solutions from all cloud providers and if you're in their stack then those products might make sense, but it is not good practice to expose your app to :80 or :443 directly. Especially with Node as using a manager like PM2 will allow you to scale up to as many instances as the number of cores on your server's CPU. Not to mention it keeps your app running and restarts when there are issues.